# Removing Files after Successful Extraction unrar rm shopt globstar

Tags: bash, unix, script, rar

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.rar; do
    dir=`dirname "$f"`;
    unrar e "$f" "$dir" && rm -frv "${f::-2}*";
done
```

From echoing out testing the rm command, the file is the correct path.  I don't receive any errors about an incorrect path or anything.  I know there are other methods to use find, but that would be pointless and use extra cpu cycles this should be working from everything I found.  Any ideas on how to use the rm command properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with removing the double quotes:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.rar; do
    dir=`dirname "$f"`;
    unrar e "$f" "$dir" && rm -frv ${f::-2}*;
done
```

---

Bash expansion of the star char `*` doesn't occurs inside quotes.

For example:

`echo dir/*.rar` might give:

```
dir/file1.rar
dir/file2.rar
dir/file3.rar
```

But `echo "dir/*.rar"` will give:

```
dir/*.rar
```

(`rm` command will try to delete a filename which contains literally a star character.)

Comment: Hey thank you so much!

I should have interpreted the output of the error by it not finding the filename/r* as a literal search for that.  I was just confused on the echo displaying it correct.